# Linear Referencing and Z measurements

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, 3d, linear-referencing

I am trying to build a linear reference route that uses the DEM derived distance instead of the default 2D distance. I have tried this How To (https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008984) by Esri but it ends up using the 2D distance instead (I have checked it multiple times - but no change).

Does anyone have a recommendation on what to do or what tool to use?